# Contest Problem linked to Fibonacci and Number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the Fibonacci sequence 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ... What are the last three digits (from left to right) of the 2020th term?

I tried using formulae for nth term of Fibonacci series using generating function and then apply binomial expansion to eliminate irrational terms and then apply mod 1000. I couldn’t make much headway. Is there a smarter way to solve this problem given we have 7 to 8 minutes to solve in contest settings.

Comment: Please post a link to this contest.  Is it ongoing?

Comment: calculators are allowed? even though using the formula for the nth fibonacci term is not feasible. as the last 3 digits are asked, there must be a smarter way. 
we would perhaps need to bring mod(1000) to get the last 3 terms

Comment: I would start by considering the sequence in $\mod 1000$.

Comment: The contest has concluded on June 2020. No calculators are allowed.

Comment: Pleaser post a link to the contest.  I don't see how to do it with pencil and paper.  It's easy to get the answer $\pmod 8$ but $\pmod {125}$ takes a little effort.  Not much, really, but a calculator sure helps.

Comment: In mod 1000, apparently the period is 1500 : http://oeis.org/A096363

Comment: @MattiP  In general, the last $d$ digits are periodic with period $15\times 10^{d-1}$, at least for $d≥3$.  See, e.g., [this](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/1-4/jarden.pdf).  But this is hardly a well known (or obvious) result.  In this case, all you need is the period $\pmod {125}$ but as that is $500$, pencil and paper seems unlikely to succeed.

Comment: ...the period is $20$ $\pmod 5$ and that is an easy, pencil and paper, computation.  Maybe there's a quick way to deduce that $500$ works $\pmod {125}$ from that, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: I would really appreciate a solution, if possible

Comment: FWIW, here's a [fast Fibonacci calculator](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVkM1KxDAUhfd5isOIkszUtom4KVNx5W5AdOFCRNJOagNtOqQpIuK7m5T-zFy4i5zv5Obk9nX3TWvXNnSz2ZB9ffdw6I5DIy2edNEZWZZ6n3iVvCqHNqChh-uQouosTo3UZnXCDG2hbB8TP4wxcoU3q51TBsUPng8QL9p8QaSCxymP-T151MYpK0tHjqpCpQtqci6i-aE8ZRmBr5HK3n2OlgilLGuV_6YZ0gg8A_-bjKF0BQMfazStciir3GAn8m4-FtYiBzXYgTMkCcQCZITCs-XtFrfeE50JbPH6o7dKbH3v_LWt7zHLDThU0ytQMUMW6Hni6ceXccPE63xmC5rjh2B6nTJ9LkijdrJ-u3RdG2P_8wyEKw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), written in Python, that can handle modulus.

Comment: I wonder if [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3981804/843178) helps. I have got time to look at the theorem it quoted from a paper.

Answer (score 3):

By the CRT it’s enough to figure out $F_{2020}$ mod $8$ and $125$.

It’s easy to check that six applications of the linear recurrence relation turn $(0,1)=(F_0,F_1)$ into $(F_6,F_7)=(8,13)=5 \cdot (0,1)$ mod $8$. As the multiplicative order of $5$ mod $8$ is two, it follows that $F_n$ mod $8$ has a period of $12$. Now note that $2020$ is congruent to $4$ mod $12$ so $F_{2020}$ is congruent to $3$ mod $8$.

Now mod $125$. That one is trickier and I’ll need some matrix formalism. Note that five times the recurrence relation turn $(0,1)$ into $(5,8)=5 \cdot (1,1)+3 \cdot (0,1)$ and turn $(1,1)$ into $(F_6,F_7)=(8,13)=8 \cdot (1,1)+5 \cdot (0,1)$, so mod $5$, five times the recurrence relation means multiplication by three.

In other words, let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1& 0\end{bmatrix}$ be the matrix representing the recurrence relation for the pair $(F_{n+1},F_n)$, then $A^5$ mod $5$ is three times the identity, ie $A^5=3I+5B_1$ for some integer matrix $B$. Thus $A^{20}=I+5B$ for some integer matrix $B$.

Now, mod $125=5^3$, $A^{20n}=I+5nB+25\frac{n(n-1)}{2}B^2$, so to get the identity matrix on the right-hand side we can choose $n=25$. It follows that $F_n$ mod $125$ is $500$-periodic and $F_{2020}$ mod $125$ is $F_{20}$ mod $25$.

Now, we can check (without a calculator) that (all mod $125$) $F_{12}=19,F_{13}=-17$, so $F_{14}=2,F_{15}=-15,F_{16}=-13,F_{17}=-28,F_{18}=-41,F_{19}=-69,F_{20}=15$.

Finally, it follows that $F_{2020}=515$ mod $1000$ (I hope).

Comment: @lulu: Corrected, thanks!

Comment: Answer indeed in 515 but how should we tackle using CRT

Comment: I gave you the remainders of $F_{2020}$ mod $8$ and $125$, to find which is the right class mod $1000$ you can brute force, there are eight possibilities.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705373/prove-that-f-125n-is-divisible-by-125